# Why does the sign of Regression coefficients for standardized & unstandardize data using R differ

Tags: r, regression, least-squares

I'm doing a liner regression fit using R. I used `lm()` to do the regression. Then I standardize my data using `scale()` and again do the regression on standardize data using `lm()`.

Surprisingly the regression coefficient of one variable was positive before standardization and after standardization I found it is showing negative coefficient. I checked the correlation between that variable and my predictor. It has positive significant correlation.

```
data_bd2=data_2[,c(1:3,5:7)] 
str(data_bd2) 
fit_bd=lm(data_bd2) 
vif(fit_bd) 
summary(fit_bd) 
scale_data_bd2=data.frame(scale(data_bd2))
colnames(scale_data_bd2)=colnames(data_bd2) 
fit_bd_std=lm(scale_data_bd2) 
summary(fit_bd_std)
```

Can you please help me understand why sign of regression coefficient differ before and after standardization?

Comment: could you show your code in R?

Comment: Hi Nick, here is my code data_bd2=data_2[,c(1:3,5:7)]

str(data_bd2)
fit_bd=lm(data_bd2)
vif(fit_bd)
summary(fit_bd)

scale_data_bd2=data.frame(scale(data_bd2))
colnames(scale_data_bd2)=colnames(data_bd2)
fit_bd_std=lm(scale_data_bd2)
summary(fit_bd_std)

Comment: Why don't you use the ''formula='' ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't ger fcop!!

Comment: Usually you specify a formula in 'lm' like 'lm(formula=y~x, data=scale_data_bd2) ?

Comment: Actually I took all my independent varaibles & dependent variable in the data frame data_bd2 with my dependent variable as the first column.By default lm consider first column of data frame as dependent & remaining as independent.So no need of formula. You can refer last comment of this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380300/shortcut-using-lm-in-r-for-formula

Comment: what is the data type of the columns 1:3 and 5:7 ?

Comment: Data type is number

Comment: as @Matthew Gunn (+1) says there must be something wrong with your code I think

Comment: Can you show us the result of str() and summary() applied to each of your datasets (ie the unscaled one and the scaled one)?

Comment: Here is the str() of my data $ Var1           : num 
 $ Var2           : num 
 $ Var3      : num  
 $ Var4                 : num  
 $ Var5            : num
 $ Var6   : Time-Series  from 1 to 104. I'm not posting summary here as it is a client data, I might get into trouble for posting that

Answer (score 5):

Your code is somehow bugged, and the sign shouldn't change.

The ordinary least squares estimator is:
$$ b = (X'X)^{-1} X'y $$

Let $A$ be some invertible linear transformation. Our transformed data is:
$$ \hat{X} =  X A$$

The OLS estimator on the transformed data is:
$$ \begin{align*} \hat{b} 
&= (A'X'XA)^{-1} A'X'y \\
&= A^{-1} (X'X)^{-1} A'^{-1}A'X'y \\
&= A^{-1} b \end{align*}
$$

The coefficients $\hat{b}$ you estimate using the transformed data should be a linear transformation (using $A^{-1}$) of the coefficients $b$ you estimate using the original data.

If you're simply standardizing $X$, what should $A$ look like? If the last column of $X$ is a column of ones (because a constant is including in the regression), then $A$ would be something like:
$$ A = \left[ \begin{array}{cccc} \frac{1}{\sigma_x} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{\sigma_y} & 0 \\ - \frac{\mu_x}{\sigma_x} & - \frac{\mu_y}{\sigma_y} & 1  \end{array} \right] $$

Multiplying $X$ by $A$ is basically equivalent to subtracting the mean for each non-constant column and dividing by the standard deviation.

$$ A^{-1} = \left[ \begin{array}{cccc} {\sigma_x} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & {\sigma_y} & 0 \\ \mu_x & \mu_y & 1  \end{array} \right] $$

$$ \hat{b}_x = \sigma_x b_x \quad \quad \hat{b}_y = \sigma_y b_y  \quad \quad \hat{b}_1 = b_1 + b_x \mu_x + b_y \mu_y $$

And so the sign of estimates for variables shouldn't change (except the sign for the constant may change). If you don't include a constant though in the regression, all bets are off.

Comment: But my sign of estimates for variable is changing not the constant & intuitively also it is looking meaning less to me but I can't able to identify the problem

Comment: They don't only scale `X`. They scale `y` too.

Comment: To understand the regression they run, check out `as.formula(iris[,-5])`